# Modifying framebuffer (/dev/graphics/fb0) parameters using a Loadable Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

**Problem:** I have to configure various LCD displays to be used by Android Platform. Almost in all cases there are no electrical specifications freely available for LCD displays on interest. But through experience and reverse engineering the parameters can be guessed reasonably well. I am trying to use Loadable Kernel Modules to fine tune the display parameters (any other suggestions are welcome too). Please find the relevant information below.

**HW:** Atmel SAMA5D31-EK (ARM 5 processor)

**SW:** Andriod Linux (Target), Ubuntu (Host System), Sourcery CodeBench (Cross Compiler) 
Code Snippets from board-dt.c file

```
static struct fb_videomode at91_tft_vga_modes[] = {
..... 
.xres =435;
.yres =235;
....
}
static struct fb_monspecs at91fb_default_monspecs = {
.........
.modedb = at91_tft_vga_modes,
......
}
static struct atmel_lcd_fb_info __initdata ek_lcdc_data = {
..........
.default_monspecs = & at91fb_default_monspecs;
.........
}
```

I added this code so the Loadable Kernel Module has access to lcdc_data structure

```
extern void set_fb_video(struct fb_videomode *mg_set_tft_vga_modes)
{
   ek_lcdc_data.default_monspecs->modedb->xres = mg_set_tft_vga_modes->xres;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(set_fb_video);
```

When I execute the loadable kernel module I don’t notice any change in the display. I suspect although I am changing the variable (memory) but registers are not been affected.

**Question**: What am I missing? I have read about making calls to platform_driver_register() and platform_driver_unregister().

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some logging in the in-kernel (non module) driver so it displays the state of the value you are trying to change.  But also, you are going to have to think about when these values, maintained in the *software program* that is the kernel, will get pushed into the hardware.  You may have to figure out how to "kick" the driver in order to get it to write the hardware registers - though perhaps going to and from sleep mode would do that?

Comment: Also, you might consider doing your hardware probing using a more normal linux, if that gives you greater ability to adjust things at runtime (as seemed to be implied in your first link), then once you know what you want you could modify the in-kernel android driver.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thank you for the feedback. I believe using fbset might be the less complicated method. I have posted a link on e2e.ti.com that might have the solution.